# How to update already uploaded file in azure container using android

Tags: android, azure, azure-storage

I have created windows azure container and uploaded the text file. Now i want to add some more data into that uploaded file (instead of downloading the file, updating and again uploading). Is it possible to update the file which is already uploaded in azure using android?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you can wait for a few more days, a new blob type called `Append Blob` is coming. IMO, that blob type will be ideal for this requirement of yours. You can read more about this upcoming functionality here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/04/13/introducing-azure-storage-append-blob.aspx.

It you can't wait till the time this new blob type comes out, you can achieve the same with block blobs as well (I would recommend for you to wait if you can). However the process is rather convoluted:

1. First, you have to ensure that no matter what's the size of the blob it is always uploaded using chunking. It doesn't matter if the chunk size is equal to the text file size but the upload should be done using `uploadBlock` and `commitBlockList` mechanism.
2. Next, when you're ready to update the contents you will first fetch the block list (using `downloadBlockList`). Then you will upload the latest data using `uploadBlock` and then call `commitBlockList` which includes the latest block id along with existing block ids.

Answer (score 0):

If your application context (android or any client that consumes storage) has the data that needs to completely overwrite your existing blob text, then you need not download it and update, but instead directly upload the new text or blob with the same name, which will overwrite it.

Otherwise if you want to first know what the blob contains and then based on some conditions do some conditional updates to the text then you need to download the blob contents and update it.

**Edge case** - if your text is very small try using the metadata properties to store the text data, so that it would be lighter to set and get the metadata details rather than completely downloading the blob.

Comment: thanks for your replay ,  i don't want to completely overwrite the blob text ,i just want to add more data to that same file(existing file in azure container ). without again downloading ,updating  and uploading. is it possible ?

Comment: Will it always be the case that you will append data to the existing file?

Comment: yes , i want to append with previous data every time.

Comment: Existing capability will force you to download and upload again, but there is something called Append Blob which is not yet publicly available. Check this out  - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/04/13/introducing-azure-storage-append-blob.aspx

Comment: @MaheshJasti Not true regarding download/upload again. I am including a workaround as a separate answer. +1 on Append Blob.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to identify other alternatives to blob if you can summarize your requirements like you need it for storing logs, audit records etc. to understand the data structure and pumping flows.